# The Event Calender Plugin - Avoid bad requests. Am i the only one facing this issue?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a WordPress site with **The Event Calendar** Plugin for my client's website and the site loads perfectly with no issue.

But when i check the site with https://gtmetrix.com/ I get this error.

`The following requests are returning 404/410 responses. Either fix the broken links, or remove the references to the non-existent resources.`

After Google for some time i tried with http://www.brokenlinkcheck.com/ and it gives me this error.

`Failed to connect to http://www.ira-upskills.com/ with HTTP Response code 404.  If the domain name above is correct and your website is up then possibly`

I set the theme back to default *Twenty Fifteen* and still i get the same error.

I try contacting the hosting service and they have no idea.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you gave site address maybe we could find the problematic request.

Comment: @ata I have updated the address in the error code.

Comment: I checked it. It's weird, sorry I cannot help this way.